# How to solve slow scrolling in UITableView - using the YouTube API

Tags: xcode, performance, api, scroll, youtube

I'm working with the google YouTube API, and I'm using this code found here http://pastebin.com/vmV2c0HT

The Code that slows things down is this one here 
`cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];`

When I remove that code it scrolls smoothly. Any idea on how I can go about having it load the images from google but still scroll smoothly? I've read some of the answers on loading images in a different way, but I still can't figure out how I'll make that work with the code I'm using.

Any help will be appreciated.

Bellow is the full code.

```
   #import "RootViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController (PrivateMethods)
- (GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *)youTubeService;
@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize feed;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"loading");

    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

    NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads;
    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:@"BmcCarmen"
                                                         userFeedID:uploadsID];



    [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithFeed:error:)];

    [super viewDidLoad];    
}

- (void)request:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedBase *)aFeed
          error:(NSError *)error {

    self.feed = (GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *)aFeed;

    [self.tableView reloadData];


}


#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}






// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[feed entries] count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    GDataEntryBase *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *title = [[entry title] stringValue];
    NSArray *thumbnails = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];

    cell.textLabel.text = title;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[thumbnails objectAtIndex:0] URLString]]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100.0f;
}




- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
}


- (GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *)youTubeService {
    static GDataServiceGoogleYouTube* _service = nil;

    if (!_service) {
        _service = [[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc] init];


        [_service setShouldCacheDatedData:YES];
        [_service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
    }

    // fetch unauthenticated
    [_service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:nil
                                    password:nil];

    return _service;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

GCD is a wonderful thing. Here is what I do:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"youTubeCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        // Configure the cell.
        GDataEntryBase *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *title = [[entry title] stringValue];
        NSArray *thumbnails = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];

        cell.textLabel.text = title;
        // Load the image with an GCD block executed in another thread
        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("image downloader", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[thumbnails objectAtIndex:0] URLString]]];
            UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{            
                cell.imageView.image = image;
                cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        });
        dispatch_release(downloadQueue);

        return cell;
    }
```

Scrolling is now super smooth. The only drawback is that when you scroll quickly, cells are re-used and sometimes the images change as new ones come in.

Comment: This has immensely improved my tableview performance, however as you mention it can reuse data when scrolling fast or I sometimes get images popping in if I scroll quickly. Is there no way around this? Just it looks rather flickery otherwise.